# Multiple service providers using same-named DI parameter (Angular 2)

Tags: angular2-services, angular2-components, angular2-providers

In my Angular 2 project, I am using 2 different services in a single component. They both have required Injector parameters. The issue I am trying to resolve is that both DI parameters use the same name, but I do not know how to format my component providers to specify the values for each unique service.

*For example:*

*Service1 constructor*: `@Inject('page') public page: string`

*Service2 constructor*: `@Inject('page') public page: string`

In my component, I set the providers as follows:

```
@Component({
...
providers: [
Service1,
{provide: 'page', useValue: 'test1'},
Service2,
{provide: 'page', useValue: 'test2'}
]
...})
```

**I want to pass the unique 'page' values to each service, but both services end up getting the value 'test2' for the DI parameter.**

How can I write my component providers in a way that will pass the right parameter values to their associated service?